# Mailparser ignores attachments' headers

Tags: email-attachments, nodemailer

I'm sending an email with attachments, which look like

```
const attachment = { filename, path, size, headers: { uid: 'someId' } };
```

According to the Nodemailer's docs I can set attachment's headers in the same format as message headers.
At the receiver's side the email is parsed by simpleParser (from mailparser). Parsed email looks great, it has all attachment's info but the headers are empty `{}`. But the raw email source has the following:

```
----_NmP-30615c8ac620489d-Part_1
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=attachment.jpg
Uid: someId
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=attachment.jpg
```

The uid header is there, but it is lost after parsing.
Also tried headers in the following format: `headers: [{ header: 'uid', value: 'someId' }]`. But it doesn't help.

How can I get that headers correctly? Or this can be the mailparser's bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of mailparser's source code researching I discovered that mailparser returns headers as Map, that's why it looks like *Object {}* which seems to be empty, but it's not.